# Crystal Report - Show row only when certain codes present

Tags: crystal-reports

hoping someone is able to assist me. Been trying to figure this out for months.

I'm working on a meal report. The report currently shows peoples mid meals: morning tea, afternoon tea and supper.

I'm trying to have the report show breakfast, lunch and dinner as well, but only if there is a mid meal present. So exclude or suppress when its only breakfast lunch and dinner, but show if its breakfast and supper for example.

My issue is from the database table the 6 meal times are all the same database field so I can't figure out a way to have the functionality I want. I can only show all breakfast, lunch, dinner or show none.

Is there a formula or something else I can use to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your (simplified) table schema, sample data, expected results - currently it is not clear, where your problem may lie. Then - can you create new views in database? Such kind of problems (ignore something if not exists another something) are often much simpler to solve at database/view level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are grouping the report on Customer, create a formula that returns 1 for mid-meal and zero otherwise. 
Then, create a Group selection formula that requires the SUM of that formula at the Customer level to be more than zero.

The Group Selection formula would be something like:

```
Sum({@TheIfFormula},{YourGroupByField}) > 0
```

Comment: So something like, if ({mealtime} in ['supper','afternoontea','morningtea']) then 1 else 0                  Just tried that and get 1.00 next to the mid meals and 0.00 next to breakfast lunch dinner         I'll try to a sum formula and see how that goes thanks.

Comment: any suggestion on what the group selection formula might look like?

Comment: Sum({@TheIfFormula},{YourGroupByField}) > 0